# copy Modul1 from Workbook1 to Workbook2

Tags: excel, vba

Workbook2 is opened by Sub `Workbook_Open` of Workbook1.
Then I have deleted Modul1 in Workbook2 and now I want to copy Modul1 from Workbook1 to Workbook2.
Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Regards Wicki

Comment: See [Chip Pearson's excellent write-up](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/vbe.aspx) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have found a solution.
I have to take care of various workbooks at different locations.
All workbooks have the same vba-code in Modul1.
If the code changes, I want the new file "Modul1.bas" provide for automatic
updating of Workbooks.
It follows the update-code in 'Modul2' of each Workbook.
Call the code with Ctrl+u (for example)

```
Sub Wu() 'shortcut Ctrl+u
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
      .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents("Modul1")
'      would be inserted as a Modul11
'      .VBComponents.Import ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Modul1.bas"
    End With
    'Start Wv after 2 sec
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "Wv"
End Sub
Sub Wv()
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
      .VBComponents.Import ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Modul1.bas"
    End With
End Sub
```

regards Wicki